# .NET : How to find the source code for a line of code using the exe and pdb file

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

I need to find the source code for a line of code using the exe and pdb file.  The exe and pdb files are written in c#.  An error was generated and the Stacktrace states a line number that does not sync with my source code line numbers since the exe was compiled a while ago.  I am trying to figure out the line of code that is causing the issue as it relates to the exe.

Comment: Try decompiling the code and looking at the results.  The line numbers may not match up, but the stacktrace will.  https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

Comment: How do you mean the PDB was written in C#?

Comment: If the line numbers do not match up, how would I figure out what line of code caused the error using the decompiler?

Comment: You can also try the IL Dissassembly utility. You can find it in the VS Developer Command prompt with the command: `ildasm`. Just drag and drop the EXE onto it to have it decompile and show you the underlying code.

Comment: typically if I know source code is broken that I haven't written I tend to go into global.asax and catch them on application error and put that data into a logger, vs sifting through stack trace code but I am the lucky one.

Comment: I don't see how I can take these suggestions and go from the stacktrace line number and find the line of code in the disassembly/decompiling that it relates to.

Comment: Are you not able to reproduce the error locally?

Comment: My source is not in sync with the exe and no, I cannot repro.  All I am trying to do is find the line of code from the exe and pdb files that is referenced in the Stacktrace.

Comment: Even if you had the original source code, the stack trace line numbers are unlikely to align with the source code because of C# compiler and JIT optimizations.

Comment: @mikez I don't understand that. Can you explain? Are you saying PDBs in general aren't guaranteed to align with source even if you have the "matching" version of source + pdb + executable?

Comment: @user31673, you can do this without lines numbers.  The stack trace will tell you what call failed.  If Foo() has only one call to Bar(), and Bar() threw an exception, you will know exactly what line in Foo() was problematic.  If instead you're seeing a NullReference exception, you'll have to assume that any dot could be the problem.  In `myvar.Foo()`, myvar could be null.  This is one reason they say that you should write many small methods instead of few big methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: you can't get the original source code from the EXE and PDB.

Neither the PDB nor the executable contain the original source code. PDBs contain a mapping between IL and source file line numbers. So if your source file has changed (it has in this context), the PDB will be mapping IL to (possibly) incorrect lines in the source file.

To get the exact source code of the line throwing the exception... you need the original source code. If you are using version control, you need to find the commit from which the .exe was built. The exe may (but won't necessarily) have useful version information that could help you get back to the exact version of source your exe was compiled from.

Concrete example: at my company, we use continuous integration that creates a unique version / build number every time code is compiled through it. It also lets you see, for a given version number, the code that was used to build this, through a link to the Github commit that triggered the CI build. So in my case, I'd look at the .exe file and get the version / build number (you should be able to easily find how to do this). I'd then go to CI, find that build, and the navigate to Github in my case to get the commit hash I'd need to check out to debug, I'd check out that version of the code, and voila, the PDB line numbers should reliably match up to the code I'm looking at.

If you don't use CI, you could try less reliable methods for figuring out what the exe was built from. For example, if you know the date the EXE was compiled on, that may give you a clue to what version of your source you should be looking at, but this wouldn't be necessarily correct.